# Gulp: write output files to subfolder relative of src path

Tags: node.js, stream, automation, gulp

I'm trying to figure out how to write a [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) task, using [PostCSS](https://github.com/postcss/postcss), so that it outputs the resulting files in the `postcss` subfolder of their original path.

Imagine you have these files:

```
/app/styles/index.css
/app/elements/pages/home.css
/app/elements/pages/profile.css
```

And you want Gulp to output the postCSS process to:

```
/app/styles/postcss/index.css
/app/elements/pages/postcss/home.css
/app/elements/pages/potcss/profile.css
```

This is my current configuration, but it doesn't work:

```
gulp.task('css', function () {
  return gulp.src([
    'app/styles/index.css',
    'app/elements/**/*.css'
  ], {base: './'})
    .pipe(gulp.postcss([require('cssnext')()]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('postcss'))
});
```

In fact, with the abive configuration Gulp will output all files with their relative subdirectories inside one `postcss` folder in the root of your project.

Any idea how to fix it? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a viable solution, using [gulp-rename](https://github.com/hparra/gulp-rename). This is the updated task configuration:

```
gulp.task('css', function () {
  return gulp.src([
    'app/styles/index.css',
    'app/elements/**/*.css'
  ], {base: './'})
    .pipe($.postcss([require('cssnext')()]))
    .pipe($.rename(function (path) {
      path.dirname += "/postcss";
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
});
```

This works perfectly. If anyone though knows a way to do it without using additinal external plugins, just through Gulp basic API, please post it. Thanks! Cheers